# Large Inputs in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to solve a problem in java which has an input consisting of 10^100 digits.
How can I take such a large input and process it.I am using JAVA as my programming language.

Comment: Where's the input coming from?

Comment: That seems pretty unheard of since exa is [`10^18`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte). You realize how much space that would take up / how big that number is? Its equivalent to a third of the atoms in the universe.

Comment: You cannot store that many digits in the observable universe.

Comment: [Googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)

Comment: (Thanks a lot, @Glenn -- now you've got me trying to invent a definition for a Guignolplex.)

Answer (score 7):

Are all those digits actually significant? Or do you just have a value like 1.234567890123456789 * 10^100?

As others have noted, having 10^100 essential digits would essentially mean you can stop now and write off your problem as uncomputable. You've either misunderstood it, or you shouldn't be approching it via brute-force number crunching. Or both.

If you *don't* need all the lower-order digits, then `float`s or `double`s may do the job for you. If you need more digits of precision than a double can handle (but still a REASONABLE number), an extended-precision floating point package such as `BigFloat` might get you there.

If you told us what you were actually trying to do, we could tell you more about whether there's any reasonable way to do it.